# Pimcore header snippet

Tags: php, cmd, pimcore

I'm trying to make header snippet on every page by adding this code to layout:

```
$s = Document_Snippet::getByPath('/snippets/');

if (is_object($s) && is_object($s->elements['header'])) 
{
echo $s->elements['header']->frontend();
}
```

In admin panel I created folder "snippets", added snippet "header" and added type "Header" to this snippet, created controller and view.

I want to display this snippet on every page but pimcore don't gets snippet object of "header". If I put this code: `echo $this->snippet("header");` it works but I need to drag&drop header snippet every time when creating new page.

In admin panel for snippet element "header" path is "/snippets/" key is "header", ID is "4".

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I tried to make it wrong way.

The right way is: `<?= $this->inc("/snippets/header") ?>`